# How to force squid users to logout?

Tags: python, mysql, linux, proxy, squid

I was trying to make squid custom authentication with python which i used to connect and check directly from MySQL Database

When user was removed from the login table , he is still able to use the proxy , the change happen only when i run :

> squid -k reconfigure

Any other helpful solution that make this happen easily and fast then using command line every time?